# Let's get critical: Jun 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Ebooks Stack Exchange](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Converting raw text to Epub](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/converting-raw-text-to-epub)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Setting up margins in ePUB and Kindle ebooks and @page rule](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/setting-up-margins-in-epub-and-kindle-ebooks-and-page-rule)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to extract epub file up to chapter one and create new epub with extracted content](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/how-to-extract-epub-file-up-to-chapter-one-and-create-new-epub-with-extracted-co)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [is DjVu still useful as a format for ebooks?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/is-djvu-still-useful-as-a-format-for-ebooks)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Body Text Formatting and Text Indentation for Kindle eBooks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/body-text-formatting-and-text-indentation-for-kindle-ebooks)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How can I toggle text reliably across all ereaders in an epub file?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/how-can-i-toggle-text-reliably-across-all-ereaders-in-an-epub-file)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Are back-of-the-book indexes useful?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/are-back-of-the-book-indexes-useful)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Using Nook outside the US](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1267/using-nook-outside-the-us)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to convert an HTML5 and JQuery featured E-book to an Executable file(exe), having inbuilt browser?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/how-to-convert-an-html5-and-jquery-featured-e-book-to-an-executable-fileexe-h)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How to convert scanned pdf to text?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/how-to-convert-scanned-pdf-to-text)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 3):

I got only 9 questions! Who stole the last one?

Seriously, I was impressed by the quality of the answers provided in the site. It's true that ebooks.SE does not have a lot of questions, but the overall quality is excellent.

Comment: If you participated in one of the questions, you won't see that question. (Or it might be there weren't enough questions in the period that met the criteria. I'm not yet sure which.)

Comment: You asked: [is DjVu still useful as a format for ebooks?](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/is-djvu-still-useful-as-a-format-for-ebooks) So you won't be able to review that one.

Comment: thanks. I thought it could have been a question I asked, but I was not really sure about it.

Comment: _"It's true that ebooks.SE does not have a lot of questions, but the overall quality is excellent."_ I think that summarizes my sentiments quite well.

Answer (score 0):

**[is DjVu still useful as a format for ebooks?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/is-djvu-still-useful-as-a-format-for-ebooks)**

Looking for answer via Google, I found another question on the site that did a pretty good job: [Conversion of djvu file into pdf file without increasing file size](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/conversion-of-djvu-file-into-pdf-file-without-increasing-file-size). But it's pretty likely that I'd just stop at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats) in the same search results. Still, when I search for [`DjVu useful`](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=DjVu+useful), it's the top result. And the answer looks fine. **Satisfactory**

**[Are back-of-the-book indexes useful?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/are-back-of-the-book-indexes-useful)**

My search turned up [Missing Entry: Whither the eBook Index?](http://newkindofbook.com/2011/09/missing-entry-whither-the-ebook-index/) That's a pretty high bar to clear and this question didn't turn up in my searching until I added the word "useful". The answer is fine—as far as it goes.  But this would be a great place to explain the pros and cons of indexing. (The number one con is that a good index is harder than it looks.) **Needs Improvement**

**[Using Nook outside the US](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1267/using-nook-outside-the-us)**

Shows up on the first page of results and is pretty clear about the answer for the fairly narrow question. (Can you load books in the EPUB format outside of the US? Yes.) But there are lots of answers that come before in the search results that are more detailed. The question could use some editing and the comment on the question outscores the answer (and is more detailed to boot). If I landed on the ebooks.SE result, I'd probably hit the back button and look elsewhere. **Needs Improvement**

**[Converting raw text to Epub](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/converting-raw-text-to-epub)**

A [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/34619/how-do-i-convert-a-text-file-to-the-epub-format) outranks this one unless I add the word "raw" to my search results. I actually prefer the answer here, but because the search terms I used are a bit unlikely, this is only a **Satisfactory** result.

**[Setting up margins in ePUB and Kindle ebooks and @page rule](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/setting-up-margins-in-epub-and-kindle-ebooks-and-page-rule)**

Top result in my search, well-written question, and a useful answer. The one niggle I have is that the OP's comment was left unaddressed. Even so, **Excellent**.

**[Body Text Formatting and Text Indentation for Kindle eBooks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/body-text-formatting-and-text-indentation-for-kindle-ebooks)**

I didn't bother to search for this question since I count two separate queries. The OP should have been instructed to ask a new question about paragraph indentation. **Needs Improvement**

**[How to convert an HTML5 and JQuery featured E-book to an Executable file(exe), having inbuilt browser?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/how-to-convert-an-html5-and-jquery-featured-e-book-to-an-executable-fileexe-h)**

Well, I was able to find this question easily enough; it ranked higher than a number of services to do what the question is asking. But the answer is somewhat sparse. Really, the question isn't great since the OP really needs to explain what their problem actually is. It's a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). **Needs Improvement**

**[How to convert scanned pdf to text?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/how-to-convert-scanned-pdf-to-text)**

I searched several different ways and couldn't find this question. The answer was spot on and useful, but there are just too many services that dominate the PageRank for the relevant search terms. **Needs Improvement**

**[How to extract epub file up to chapter one and create new epub with extracted content](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/how-to-extract-epub-file-up-to-chapter-one-and-create-new-epub-with-extracted-co)**

Ebooks.SE comes up on top in my searching. Unfortunately, this question is behind: [How can I extract some chapters or sections from an ebook into a new one?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/how-can-i-extract-some-chapters-or-sections-from-an-ebook-into-a-new-one) Given the choice, I'd prefer several narrower questions to the more general one. But the EPUB-specific answer is darn useful in any case. **Satisfactory**

**[How can I toggle text reliably across all ereaders in an epub file?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/how-can-i-toggle-text-reliably-across-all-ereaders-in-an-epub-file)**

I appreciate the question *and* the answer. It's odd that the answer hasn't been upvoted; perhaps if [this comment were edited in](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/1242/#comment1526_1242) it would be. I found the question after adding the word "toggle" to my search. **Satisfactory**

---

More than most sites I've reviewed, ebooks.SE lacks a serious presence in Google's index. I don't know why and I wish I did. It's not often that a Stack Exchange site has a sudden drop in traffic that can't be explained by Google changing their algorithm. But this site has fallen dramatically since mid-March:

[image: ebooks.SE Quantcast traffic]

I admit I was one of the [86%](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400) who failed to follow through on their commitment. But I'm puzzled about what's gone wrong here. Other than a severe drop in traffic and a somewhat challenging search space, I can't pinpoint any particular causes.